# Get data from Eloquent via relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 models: A, B and C.

```
class A{
    public function b(){
        return $this->hasMany(B::class, 'a_id', 'id');
   }
 }

class B{
    public function c(){
        return $this->hasOne(C::class, 'b_id', 'id');
   }
 }
```

I am trying to create two queries. First, retrieve only the data from model A where for each model B exist relation C and the value of the title column in C is different from null. Second, retrieve only the data from model A where there is at least one relationship from B to C and the value of the title column in C is null.

A:
| id | value |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1    | a            |
| 2   | b            |
| 3   | b            |

B:
| id | a_id | value |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 1  | 1    | First |
| 2  | 1    | Second |
| 3  | 2    | Last |
| 4  | 3    | Other |
| 5  | 2    | Last Other |

C:
| id | b_id | title |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 1  | 1    | First title |
| 2  | 2    | Other title |
| 3  | 3    | null |
| 3  | 3    | Other Second title |

For this example, I want get only data with id 1 from A model for first query and only data with id 2 for second query. Thanks for help me.

Answer (score 0):

First Query: Retrieve data from model A where for each model B exists a relation to C, and the value of the title column in C is different from null:

```
$resultQuery1 = A::whereHas('b.c', function ($query) {
    $query->whereNotNull('title');
})->get();
```

Second Query: Retrieve data from model A where there is at least one relationship from B to C, and the value of the title column in C is null:

```
$resultQuery2 = A::whereHas('b.c', function ($query) {
    $query->whereNull('title');
})->get();
```